# What does this spring boot jpa hibernate error mean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

The spring boot project crashes on startup due to a spring jpa hibernate error, here are the different infos:

version spring, jpa et hibernate :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

spring-boot-starter-data-jpa version: 2.6.7
hibernate version: 5.6.8

Here is my JPA class:

```
package com.organization.config;


import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.organization.repository.test"}
)
@EntityScan(
        basePackages = {"com.organization.domain.test" }
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestConfigJPA implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}
```

Here are my properties:

```
spring:
  application.name: test-service
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
        default_schema: schema1
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    show-sql: true
    open-in-view: false
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://url:1234/databasename01
    username: user1
    password: password1
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Here is the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at ImportDataApplication.main(ImportDataApplication.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1672) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

On other project I have this same type of config that works, what can it be?

Comment: Look at the NullPointerException at ImportDataApplication.java, line 42. Why would that object be null at that moment?

Comment: InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl line 1672 is the probelm